# GoogleSignIn in React Native Firebase aplication doesn't work

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native

I was developing an React Native App which integrate Firebase as Authentication System of the App.

The App compile fine, but when I try to invoke the GoogleSignIn method, the App says the message on the AndroidToast: "Se ha producido un error. Intentelo más tarde' + error", where Error says: InvalidUserName.

The code of my login Screen was the following:

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Platform,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Keyboard,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

import {Background} from '../components/Background';
import {WhiteLogo} from '../components/WhiteLogo';
import {loginStyles} from '../theme/loginTheme';
import {useForm} from '../hooks/useForm';
import {StackScreenProps} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {AuthContext} from '../context/AuthContext';
import {signInUser} from '../api/AuthApi';
import {GoogleSignin, GoogleSigninButton} from 'react-native-google-signin';
import {auth, Providers} from '../config/firebase';
import {FirebaseUser} from '../interfaces/appInterfaces';
import {ProtectedScreen} from './ProtectedScreen';
import {ToastAndroid} from 'react-native';

interface Props extends StackScreenProps<any, any> {}

export const LoginScreen = ({navigation, route}: Props) => {
  const {signIn, errorMessage, removeError} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const {Firebase} = require('../config/firebase');
  const {email, password, onChange} = useForm({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  });
  const auth = Firebase.auth;
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  GoogleSignin.configure({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'],
    webClientId: Providers.google.PROVIDER_ID,
    offlineAccess: true,
    forceConsentPrompt: true,
    accountName: Providers.google.PROVIDER_ID,
  });

  //TODO: A lo mejor hay que usar un useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    auth().onAuthStateChanged((user: FirebaseUser) => {
      if (user) {
        setAuthenticated(true);
        return () => <ProtectedScreen />;
      }
    });
    ToastAndroid.show(
      'Do not authenticated, redirenting...',
      ToastAndroid.LONG,
    );
    //return <LoginScreen navigation={navigation} route={route} />;
  }, [authenticated]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (errorMessage.length === 0) return;

    Alert.alert('Login incorrecto', errorMessage, [
      {
        text: 'Ok',
        onPress: removeError,
      },
    ]);
  }, [errorMessage]);

  const onLogin = () => {
    console.log({email, password});
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    signIn({correo: email, password});
  };
  async function onGoogleButtonPress() {
    const {idToken} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
    return auth.signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
  }
  return (
    <>
      {/* Background */}
      <Background />

      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={{flex: 1}}
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}>
        <View style={loginStyles.formContainer}>
          {/* Keyboard avoid view */}
          <WhiteLogo />

          <Text style={loginStyles.title}>Login</Text>

          <Text style={loginStyles.label}>Email:</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Ingrese su email:"
            placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.4)"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            underlineColorAndroid="white"
            style={[
              loginStyles.inputField,
              Platform.OS === 'ios' && loginStyles.inputFieldIOS,
            ]}
            selectionColor="white"
            onChangeText={value => onChange(value, 'email')}
            value={email}
            onSubmitEditing={onLogin}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
          />

          <Text style={loginStyles.label}>Contraseña:</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="******"
            placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.4)"
            underlineColorAndroid="white"
            secureTextEntry
            style={[
              loginStyles.inputField,
              Platform.OS === 'ios' && loginStyles.inputFieldIOS,
            ]}
            selectionColor="white"
            onChangeText={value => onChange(value, 'password')}
            value={password}
            onSubmitEditing={onLogin}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
          />

          {/* Boton login */}
          <View style={loginStyles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.8}
              style={loginStyles.button}
              onPress={() => signInUser}>
              <Text style={loginStyles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          {/* Crear una nueva cuenta */}
          <View style={loginStyles.newUserContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.8}
              onPress={() => navigation.replace('RegisterScreen')}>
              <Text style={loginStyles.buttonText}>Nueva cuenta </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={loginStyles.googleButtonConteiner}>
            <GoogleSigninButton
              style={loginStyles.googleButton}
              size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
              color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
              onPress={() =>
                onGoogleButtonPress()
                  .then(() => navigation.navigate('ProtectedScreen'))
                  .catch(error =>
                    ToastAndroid.show(
                      'Se ha producido un error. Intentelo más tarde' + error,
                      ToastAndroid.LONG,
                    ),
                  )
              }
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </>
  );
};
```

And the code of my firebase.tsx was the following:

```
import firebase  from 'react-native-firebase';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import {FIREBASE_CONFIG} from '../config/config';
import { Firestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

export const Firebase = firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG, 'FirebaseApp');

export const Providers = {
    google: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider,
}

export const db = Firestore
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export default Firebase;
```

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Platform,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Keyboard,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

import {Background} from '../components/Background';
import {WhiteLogo} from '../components/WhiteLogo';
import {loginStyles} from '../theme/loginTheme';
import {useForm} from '../hooks/useForm';
import {StackScreenProps} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {AuthContext} from '../context/AuthContext';
import {signInUser} from '../api/AuthApi';
import {GoogleSignin, GoogleSigninButton} from 'react-native-google-signin';
import {auth, Providers} from '../config/firebase';
import {FirebaseUser} from '../interfaces/appInterfaces';
import {ProtectedScreen} from './ProtectedScreen';
import {ToastAndroid} from 'react-native';

interface Props extends StackScreenProps<any, any> {}

export const LoginScreen = ({navigation, route}: Props) => {
  const {signIn, errorMessage, removeError} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const {Firebase} = require('../config/firebase');
  const {email, password, onChange} = useForm({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  });
  const auth = Firebase.auth;
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  GoogleSignin.configure({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'],
    webClientId: Providers.google.PROVIDER_ID,
    offlineAccess: true,
    forceConsentPrompt: true,
    accountName: Providers.google.PROVIDER_ID,
  });

  //TODO: A lo mejor hay que usar un useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    auth().onAuthStateChanged((user: FirebaseUser) => {
      if (user) {
        setAuthenticated(true);
        return () => <ProtectedScreen />;
      }
    });
    ToastAndroid.show(
      'Do not authenticated, redirenting...',
      ToastAndroid.LONG,
    );
    //return <LoginScreen navigation={navigation} route={route} />;
  }, [authenticated]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (errorMessage.length === 0) return;

    Alert.alert('Login incorrecto', errorMessage, [
      {
        text: 'Ok',
        onPress: removeError,
      },
    ]);
  }, [errorMessage]);

  const onLogin = () => {
    console.log({email, password});
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    signIn({correo: email, password});
  };
  async function onGoogleButtonPress() {
    const {idToken} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
    return auth.signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
  }
  return (
    <>
      {/* Background */}
      <Background />

      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={{flex: 1}}
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}>
        <View style={loginStyles.formContainer}>
          {/* Keyboard avoid view */}
          <WhiteLogo />

          <Text style={loginStyles.title}>Login</Text>

          <Text style={loginStyles.label}>Email:</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Ingrese su email:"
            placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.4)"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            underlineColorAndroid="white"
            style={[
              loginStyles.inputField,
              Platform.OS === 'ios' && loginStyles.inputFieldIOS,
            ]}
            selectionColor="white"
            onChangeText={value => onChange(value, 'email')}
            value={email}
            onSubmitEditing={onLogin}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
          />

          <Text style={loginStyles.label}>Contraseña:</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="******"
            placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.4)"
            underlineColorAndroid="white"
            secureTextEntry
            style={[
              loginStyles.inputField,
              Platform.OS === 'ios' && loginStyles.inputFieldIOS,
            ]}
            selectionColor="white"
            onChangeText={value => onChange(value, 'password')}
            value={password}
            onSubmitEditing={onLogin}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
          />

          {/* Boton login */}
          <View style={loginStyles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.8}
              style={loginStyles.button}
              onPress={() => signInUser}>
              <Text style={loginStyles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          {/* Crear una nueva cuenta */}
          <View style={loginStyles.newUserContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.8}
              onPress={() => navigation.replace('RegisterScreen')}>
              <Text style={loginStyles.buttonText}>Nueva cuenta </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={loginStyles.googleButtonConteiner}>
            <GoogleSigninButton
              style={loginStyles.googleButton}
              size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
              color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
              onPress={() =>
                onGoogleButtonPress()
                  .then(() => navigation.navigate('ProtectedScreen'))
                  .catch(error =>
                    ToastAndroid.show(
                      'Se ha producido un error. Intentelo más tarde' + error,
                      ToastAndroid.LONG,
                    ),
                  )
              }
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </>
  );
};
```

I hope you can guess where the error could be, and if like this take thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are nor passing accessToken in credentials.

change

```
async function onGoogleButtonPress() {
    const {idToken} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
    return auth.signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
  }
```

to

```
async function onGoogleButtonPress() {
    const {idToken, accessToken} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken, accessToken);
    return auth.signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
  }
```